# Starting C++ on Mac OS Sierra

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos

I want to learn C++. I am using my MacBook Pro for this. I used to have dev-C++ on my old laptop. I installed eclipse neon on my Mac and Xcode as well.

After typing a "hello world" program, I selected "Build All" option. But when I select run, it just displays a "hello world" on the bottom like this:
[image]

How can I open a console window like dev C++? I tried using "run as>local application" . But it says "binary not found".

Sometimes, it looks like "run as > none applicable"

Comment: as far as I can see the program worked. The environment in which your program runs is nothing to do with your program. It's provided by the shell or development environment.

Comment: @RichardHodges Is there any other application for C++ which is more user-friendly than eclipse?

Comment: Xcode is free on OSX. I use CLion which will cost you money, but is fantastic (in my view). CLion requires some knowledge of CMake. You can try it for free for a month. There is also netbeans with the c++ addin. In my view (flame suit on) eclipse is the worst of all of them.

Comment: If you want a console, just open a console (terminal).

Comment: @RichardHodges maybe he can have it for free with some student package. Depend where he is. I was able to have it (still can I think), but I use neovim.

Comment: @MathieuVanNevel haven't tried neovim - will do so, thank you. One thing to say about CLion is that you don't even want to consider it for a large project unless you have 16GB of ram. And even then...

Comment: @RichardHodges _I haven't tried neovim - will do so_, well neovim is not a IDE like CLion. But you can do something pretty similar if you have [some patience](http://tuxdiary.com/2015/02/15/yavide/). I'm going out of the topic, so I'll leave (didn't wanted to be hated sorry ^^).